# asp.net mvc html.labelfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) %>

public ActionResult EditUser(string UserName)
{
    //to do some thing
}
```

I have a label on my .aspx page and i have a button which calls edit user button in controller. The value of username is not being passed. I am getting a null. How can  I get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [LabelFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg401864.aspx) helper simply generates a `<label>` tag whose value is never sent to the server when you submit the form. You could use a hidden field in order to include the value when the form is submitted:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserName) %>
```

Also sending the username in a GET/POST request seems like a security risk. If your site is using authentication I would recommend you fetching the username of the authenticated user from the authentication cookie.